# Correct MD5 hash in javascript for all filetypes

Tags: javascript, md5

Using the library here: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5
I am attempting to correctly hash files in MD5 using javascript.

So far I get correct hashes for text files but if I attempt to hash an image file I get an incorrect hash.

This could be due to how the javascript FileReader reads the larger image files. I have tried readAsBinaryString(), readAsArrayBuffer() and readAsText() none of which provide the correct hash with the given library.

How should I be reading the file for this to provide a correct hash for all filetypes, is there a more appropriate library that works for all filetypes I should be using?

HTML:

```
<input id="file-to-hash" type=file>
<button onclick="hashFile()">Hash</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function hashFile() {

 var file = document.getElementById('file-to-hash').files[0];

 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
 reader.onload = readSuccess;
}

function readSuccess(evt){
 fileContents = evt.target.result;
 var hash = md5(fileContents);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now the [SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) API and its [`subtle.digest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest) method.

You won't be able to get an MD5 hash from this API, because MD5 [is not considered secure anymore](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/836068).

But you'll be able to get an hash with other (more-secure) algorithms, such as SHA.

```js
function getHash(buffer, algo = "SHA-256") {
  return crypto.subtle.digest(algo, buffer)
    .then(hash => {
      // here hash is an arrayBuffer, so we'll convert it to its hex version
      let result = '';
      const view = new DataView(hash);
      for (let i = 0; i < hash.byteLength; i += 4) {
        result += ('00000000' + view.getUint32(i).toString(16)).slice(-8);
      }
      return result;
    });
}

f.onchange = e => {
  const fR = new FileReader();
  fR.onload = e => getHash(fR.result)
    .then(hash => console.log(hash))
// Chrome only accept it from an secure origin
    .catch(e => {
      if (e.code === 9) {
        console.log(`Be sure to be on the https page : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036218/`)
      } else {
        console.log(e.message)
      }
    })
  fR.readAsArrayBuffer(f.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="f">
```

Comment: I understand your point about insecurity with MD5 however I am simply trying to produce pseudo-unique hashes for all types of file.

Comment: @SamuelBarnes, and what prevents you from using a secure algo for it ?

Comment: Nothing, but this isn't the question.

Comment: @SamuelBarnes *is there a more appropriate library that works for all filetypes I should be using* There is an more appropriate API directly in the browsers that works faster than any libs you'll find.

Comment: Fair enough, it seems SubtleCrypto could be usable, I was not aware this is included in modern browsers.